# Practicable(?): Selenium webdriver with Dynamics 365 - Thread.Sleep() and "missing"- url difficulty

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm-365

So I know Selenium is working quite fine with `CRM2011` - `CRM2015`. Next year we are going to migrate our CRM System to `Dynamics 365`. 
I am unsure if the automated testing with `CRM 365` is going to work, and since I have no Testsystem yet I hope some of you guys already had the chance of trying.
I found [this](http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/miguelnepomuceno/2016/10/03/selenium-with-dynamics-crm-automating-clicks-in-navigation-groups) blog entry, but there are some issues mentioned:

1. There are no real URLs within `Dynamics 365` - which will make navigation complex(?)
2. This `Thread.Sleep()` need seems realy odd to me when wanting to wait for a site ready for interaction.

I know this is a realy broadcast question. But maybe someone got another hint I couldn't find myself (since Dynamics 365 is quite new there aren't realy many ressources around).
Have your tried `Selenium` with Dynamics 365 so far - and is it realy practicable?